# AngularJS 2 Can't Start Node Server Errors

Tags: angular

I'm building a sample app in Angular 2 and it was working fine before but now when I try to run it I get the following error in the terminal:

```
app/idea.ts(3,8): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'date'.
```

ideas.ts looks like this:

```
export class Idea {
  id: number;
  date: date;
  featured: boolean;
  content: string;
}
```

I've been having similar problems with other sample apps I've built. Does anybody know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Date is a Typescript interface in this case and should be uppercase:

```
export class Idea {
  id: number;
  date: Date;
  featured: boolean;
  content: string;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, funnily enough I just tried that and it worked so I already got it working. Thanks for your answer!